# PHP Version not compatible

Tags: php

I have a PHP file with the following code:

```
<?php

// RECEIVE POST DATA

$xml = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : file_get_contents('php://input');

//  READ XML


$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
..... rest codes here
?>
```

I was receiving xml data saved the $xml variable. Now I have a new server with PHP version 5.6.15 , I copied the same file that's worked during last three years, but now new version it doesn't work. I don't remember the old version that the file worked.

I have been told that some command was deprecated, how can I fix the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated so you can not use it.

Try This instead:

```
$xml =  file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: You need to debug your script so that you can see what is deprecated in your old file and let us know, so we can find which solution could be taken..

Comment: i run debug, no errors. but not saves the received data into $xml. Same code before moved to new server was  saving into $xml.

Comment: Probably the new server uses a lower version of PHP, so you want get the 'deprecated' error.

Comment: I don't have "deprecated" error, I have been told that maybe.  I think the problem is PHP compatibility between 5.2 to 5.6 version issues. I am running the file as is was before , without any changes, without any error messages, just worked then and not works now. That's makes the frustrating issue.